# updating QByteArray contents via reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, qt, strict-aliasing, qbytearray

Is it possible to update the contents of a **QByteArray** using **reinterpret_cast** or some other QT aliasing trick?

I have a data struct member that is wrapped in a std::unique_ptr (it is typically 12 bytes in length however sometimes it can be larger due to an array trailing field) - I need to be able to update the contents of this struct.

Due to the implicit sharing concepts in QByteArray this is tricky and I cannot find the right set of operations to mutate the underlying mpLastTxHeader member.  The member is declared as:

```
//! Last sent header - used as template to send next headers
//! as it should always contain the last sent sequence number & timestamp
std::unique_ptr<QByteArray> mpLastTxHeader;
```

The member function that uses this QByteArray member variable currently makes a deep copy of the previous contents of the QByteArray (it happens to contain an RTP header with the last sent sequence # so this is why I need to mutate and save it before the next use).  Ideally when I call 'rtpHeader->setSeqNum' the underlying mpLastTxHeader should be updated but I do not know how to do this.

```
// make a deep copy of the last sent RTP header (containing sequence# & timestamp)
const auto rawHeader = std::make_unique<QByteArray>(*mpLastTxHeader);
const auto rtpHeader = reinterpret_cast<rtp_hdr_t*>(rawHeader->data());
// create the RTP datagrams with incrementing sequence numbers and timestamps
while ((mpAudioCache->size() - mLastReadPos) >= gRAWAudioSize) {
    // reset the marker bit so it doesn't keep getting transmitted
    rtpHeader->m = 0u;
    // increment the sequence numbers
    rtpHeader->setSeqNum(rtpHeader->getSeqNum() + 1);
    // increment timestamp
    rtpHeader->setTimestamp(rtpHeader->getTimestamp() + mTSIncrement);
    // prefix the next block with the next rtp header
    QByteArrayList temp = {
        *rawHeader,
        mpAudioCache->read(gRAWAudioSize)
    };
    mTXBufferList.emplace_back(temp.join());
    mLastReadPos += gRAWAudioSize;
}
```

Comment: Any object can be viewed as an array of bytes, but the reverse is rarely true. Forcing the issue with a `reinterpret_cast` will blow up in your face in hard-to-diagnose ways more often than not. Consider `memcpy`ing the array into an instance of the structure and counting on the compiler to optimize away the overhead if it's safe to do so.

Comment: the object is actually an array of bytes as it is transmitted over UDP - the QByteArray was a convenient container to store this.   I've been using the reinterpret_cast successfully with this in places where I do not need to mutate the contents like this: const auto rawHeader = std::make_unique<QByteArray>(rHeader);
        const auto rtpHeader = reinterpret_cast<rtp_hdr_t*>(rawHeader->data());
        auto seqNum = rtpHeader->getSeqNum();
        auto timeStamp = rtpHeader->getTimestamp();

Comment: Sometimes you get lucky and don't get bit you as hard as it could, but rather than outright crashing or getting kicked in the teeth by padding, you could be taking a performance hit reading misaligned data. If you have a 32 bit variable that's in the byte array at a 16 bit boundary, the best you can hope for when accessing the variable is two reads. If you are cautious and force the correct alignment on the array ahead of time, you can do all sorts of evil and get away with it.

Comment: `mpLastTxHeader->data()` would give you direct access to raw data stored in your `QByteArray`. You can both read and write through this pointer. I'm not sure I quite grasp the nature of the difficulty. Why again do you feel the need to make a deep copy? Why not `auto rtpHeader = reinterpret_cast<rtp_hdr_t*>(mpLastTxHeader->data());`?